InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with X values, but the requested shape has Y [Op:Reshape] in Keras/TensorFlow
I am trying to implement a neural network using Keras and TensorFlow, and I encountered the following error:
InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 64 values, but the requested shape has 4096 [Op:Reshape]

Here is the code snippet that leads to this error:
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model

# Load pre-trained model
model = load_model('model.h5')

# Example input data
input_data = np.random.rand(1,64).astype(np.float32)  # Shape (1, 64)

# Convert input data to tensor
input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(input_data)

# Calculate gradients with respect to input
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(input_tensor)
    predictions = model(input_tensor)  # Error occurs here
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(predictions)

grads = tape.gradient(loss, input_tensor)

I have checked the model architecture, and I am confident that there is no Reshape layer that expects an input with 4096 elements. The input data has a shape of (1,64). Part of my model architecture is as following:

The function for creating model is as following:
#make residual tower of convolutional blocks
def make_resnet_pure(enlarge_pairs = 1, num_blocks=2, num_filters=32 * 1, num_outputs=1, d1=64, d2=64, word_size=16, ks=3, depth=5, reg_param=0.0001, final_activation='sigmoid'):
    #Input and preprocessing layers
    inp = Input(shape=(num_blocks * word_size * 2 * enlarge_pairs,));
    rs = Reshape((2 * num_blocks * enlarge_pairs, word_size))(inp);
    perm = Permute((2,1))(rs);
    conv0 = Conv1D(num_filters, kernel_size=1, padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_param))(perm);
    conv0 = BatchNormalization()(conv0);
    conv0 = Activation('relu')(conv0);
    shortcut = conv0;
    for i in range(depth):
        conv1 = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=ks, padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_param))(shortcut);
        conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1);
        conv1 = Activation('relu')(conv1);
        conv2 = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=ks, padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_param))(conv1);
        conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2);
        conv2 = Activation('relu')(conv2);
        shortcut = Add()([shortcut, conv2]);
    flat1 = Flatten()(shortcut);
    dense1 = Dense(d1, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_param))(flat1);
    dense1 = BatchNormalization()(dense1);
    dense1 = Activation('relu')(dense1);
    dense2 = Dense(d2, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_param))(dense1);
    dense2 = BatchNormalization()(dense2);
    dense2 = Activation('relu')(dense2);
    out = Dense(num_outputs, activation=final_activation, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_param))(dense2);
    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out);
    return(model);

Questions:

Why am I encountering this InvalidArgumentError when using the Reshape layer?
How can I resolve this issue to match the expected input shape for the Reshape layer?

Additional Information:
TensorFlow version: 2.15.0
Keras version: 2.15.0
Python version: 3.11.7
Thank you in advance for your help!

Can you post your full model/model creation? I tested your model part (up to, including, permute) with your code snippet and got not error. TF v2.16.1

Thank you. The function for creating model has been added. @mhenning

My bad...My actually used data's shape is (64,) instead of (1, 64)

I'm sorry, I'm still not able to reproduce your error, your code/model runs without problems for me. You load your model in the begnning of your code. Are you really sure that this loaded model has the same layers as the one you posted? Otherwise, I have no idea why it's not working..
